# For $T$ to be homomorphism it's necessary and sufficient that $b\|x\|\le \|T\cdot x\| \le c\|x\|$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Let $T\colon E\to F$ be a linear bijective transformation. For $T$ to be an
>   homomorphism, it's necessary and sufficient that exists constants
>   $b,c>0$ such that
>
> $$b\|x\|\le \|T\cdot x\| \le c\|x\|$$

Obviously I must prove linearity, that is: $T\cdot (x+y) = T\cdot x + T\cdot y$ and $T\cdot (\alpha x) = \alpha T\cdot x$.

I'm trying to deal with this:

I know that there must exists $b_1,c_1$ such that

$$b_1\|\alpha x + y\|\le T\cdot (\alpha x + y) \le c_1\|\alpha x + y\|$$

At least inequality can be applied to the right side to get $c_1\|\alpha x + y\|\le c_1(\alpha\|x\|+\|y\|)$ but I don't see how it helps.

Comment: Homomorphism of normed or topological vector space ?

Comment: I don't know but I'd say normed

Comment: Do you mean homeomorphism, as in continuous and have continuous inverse?

Comment: So $T$ is continuous and has an inverse, and it reduces to show this inverse is continuous

Comment: If $T$ is assumed to be linear why would you need to prove it? What do you mean by a  homomorphism in this context?